# Struggling to scrape asp.net with PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I am trying to scrap a site using PHP (5.6) and libcurl.

The site is implemented in asp.net and is accessed via a local proxy. Site uses HTTPS so its not very easy to get the unencrypted traffic being sent across the wire.

I'm failing at the first step - logging in.

```
$curl_options = array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
     CURLOPT_PROXY          => 'http://localproxy.example.com:8080',
     CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD   => "$proxyUser:$proxyPass",
     CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH      => CURLAUTH_NTLM,
     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
     CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER    => false,
     CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $curl_cookie_jar,
     CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>  $curl_cookie_jar
 );

 ...
 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $entryurl);
 curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
 $reply=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 ...
 $postdata=array(
     'username'=>'someuser', 'password'=>'s3cr3t',
     '__VIEWSTATE'=>$vstate, '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=>$vsgen
 );

 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
 curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata));
 $reply=curl_exec($ch);
```

In a browser, the sequence of events is as follows:

1. GET / results in 302 redirect to /Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fIndex.aspx
2. Login page returned by redirect location
3. user enters username and password and clicks on input of type submit
4. username, password, submit and 2 hidden inputs (__VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR) are POST'ed back to same URL (/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fIndex.aspx)
5. server responds with 302 redirect to /Index.asp
6. browser retrieves Index.asp (as an authenticated user)

However when I try this using a PHP script, after step 4, the response is step 2.

I have tried pointing the script at a local non-SSL website to check that Curl is doing what I expect. It is.

**Analysis**

1. Cookies are being captured and replayed
2. All required variables (including __VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR) are being populated and sent back in POST
3. content is not being cached - inserting an artificial delay between the GET and POST results in a different timestamp on the response
4. although session seems to be working, server is responding as if the POST were a GET with no parameters - if an invalid username or password is supplied in the browser, the response is different, but both the GET and the POST from scraping return the same HTML.

I have tried adding in all the extra headers generated in a browser (User-Agent, Accept, Accept-Language) with no impact.

Comment: Sadly I get exactly the same result using the code from http://www.mishainthecloud.com/2009/12/screen-scraping-aspnet-application-in.html which makes me think its something very specific to the site I'm trying to scrape (or the proxy I'm going through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I did not understand that [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html) only *writes* cookies to COOKIEJAR and *only* reads from COOKIEFILE. Indeed it seems to remove cookies from COOKIEJAR if they are not in the last response from the server (still not fully profiled this).